# Is there a way to wire up a color to a variable?

Tags: ios, paintcode

I would like to 'wire' up a 'color' variable to the an imported svg. I would like to change the color of a variable of the fill with a Stylekit method.Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Paintcode rocks.  But also of note, check out the awesome "IB_DESIGNABLE" and "IBInspectable " in modern Xcode. [tutorial](http://www.weheartswift.com/make-awesome-ui-components-ios-8-using-swift-xcode-6/) , [another](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/building-custom-ui-element-with-ibdesignable/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set it as a variable or pass it in as a parameter, using the drop down when editing a color.

[image]

Comment: Sneaky, but awesome! Cheers

Comment: Have been looking for, your answers are of great help to me!